# Function to output latex table from dictionary

Tags: tables, python, dictionaries

Does anyone know how I can get a dictionary from python  into a format that I can paste into latex to create a two column table of keys & values? I'm pretty basic with python.

E.G. a function to turn
{(1, 2): 0.34,
(1, 4): 0.44,
(2, 3): 0.34}

into:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c| } 
 \hline
 Edge & Edge centrality\\
 \hline
 (1, 2)& 0.34\\
 (1, 4)& 0.44\\
 (2, 3)& 0.34\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

I'm imaging something about using strings?

Comment: You can create a function in Python that writes the string the way you want. You may then copy and paste or create a .tex file direct from Python with the contents you need.

Comment: Welcome. // Just wondering: do you know Phyton, or any other scripting language? It's standard to put text lines into a file, like "\hline \n" . It's no big deal to split a data string into code snippets like "\t  (1, 2)& 0.34\\ \n".

Comment: This seems to be a Python question, not a TeX question.

Comment: For register and example, my [Matlab to LaTeX library](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/72155-matlab-to-latex-library) has some function to do exactly what you have in mind, but in Matlab. I intend one day replicate my library in Python, but that's a project for my future me.

Answer (score 1):

The following Python code:

```python
d = {(1, 2): 0.34, (1, 4): 0.44, (2, 3): 0.34}

def dict2ltxtab(d: dict, bare=False, headrow = None):
    if not bare:
        print(r"\begin{center}")
        print(r"\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}")
        print(r"\hline")
    if headrow and len(headrow) >= 2:
        print(headrow[0], "&", headrow[1], r"\\")
        print(r"\hline")
    for k, v in d.items():
        print(k, "&", v, r"\\")
    if not bare:
        print(r"\hline")
        print(r"\end{tabular}")
        print(r"\end{center}")
```

produces when called with `dict2ltxtab(d)`:

```tex
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
(1, 2) & 0.34 \\
(1, 4) & 0.44 \\
(2, 3) & 0.34 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

and when called as `dict2ltxtab(d, headrow=("Edge", "Edge centrality"))`:

```tex
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Edge & Edge centrality \\
\hline
(1, 2) & 0.34 \\
(1, 4) & 0.44 \\
(2, 3) & 0.34 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

If you also give `bare = True` in the arguments of `dict2ltxtab` the surrounding environments aren't included in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of what you mean with "dictionary" or a "function" in python, but if you have data that can be showed as a dataframe in python, then you can also pass this dataframe to R and convert it to a LaTeX table  on the fly, with the help of the `reticulate` (and `knitr` package to compile the document.

**Example.Rnw**

---

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

<<echo=F>>=
library(reticulate) # R interface to python
@

\subsection*{The python code} 

<<data, engine="python">>=
import pandas as pd
data = [['(1,2)',0.34],['(1,4)',0.44],['(2,3)',0.77]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Edge','Edge centrality'])
df
@

\subsection*{The \LaTeX\ table}

<<echo=F,results='asis'>>=
library(xtable)
print(xtable(py$df,caption="My python data."), 
      booktabs=T,
      caption.placement="top",
      include.rownames=F)
@

\end{document}
```